# What are these black flies/gnats on my Zucchini Blossoms?

Tags: pest-control, pests, zucchini

[image][image][image]

Trying to figure out what these bugs are and if they are bad for my zucchini plant.  I also have a video but I can’t figure out how to post it. I will edit this with a link to it if I figure it out.

Thanks!